# adding delete option for product rails member routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

My problem is that I need to add the option for delete product and I'm stock with that....

First I added this line in the index.html.erb:

```
<% glyph_to "Delete", product, method: :delete, data: (confirm: "Are you sure that product" ##(product.id) is not used?") if can? (:destroy, product)%>
```

but I don't now in that line what is the difference between "method: :delete" and  "if can? (:destroy, product)", destroy is the controller action I guess and delete? I don't know....

another thing is my controller definition for that action:

```
def destroy 
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to product_path
end
```

but when I press "delete" it doesn't redirect to product_path

and my routes definition are the following:

```
resources products do 
    member do
        get :destroy
    end
end
```

I will be very grateful of any help with this,

thank you for your time :D!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`destroy` action must be called on HTTP `DELETE` request and never on `GET`. You should definitely fix the following code from your routes:

```
resources products do  ## missing : here, it should be :products
  ## member block not required
  member do  
      get :destroy  ## destroy should never be GET request
  end
end
```

**You just need to define your routes as:**

```
resources :products ## Notice :products and not products
```

This will generate following routes for you which you can check by running command `rake routes`

```
         products GET    /products(.:format)                   products#index
                  POST   /products(.:format)                   products#create
      new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)               products#new
     edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)          products#edit
          product GET    /products/:id(.:format)               products#show
                  PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)               products#update
                  PUT    /products/:id(.:format)               products#update
                  DELETE /products/:id(.:format)               products#destroy
```

Notice the last route generated.
`destroy` action should be called as HTTP `Delete` method which is why on your link you need to specify `method: :delete` as

```
<% glyph_to "Delete", product, method: :delete, data: (confirm: "Are you sure that product" ##(product.id) is not used?") if can? (:destroy, product)%>
```

so when you click on this link a `DELETE` request would be sent which would be mapped to your route for `products#destroy`, i.e.,

```
   DELETE /products/:id(.:format)               products#destroy
```

Also, you need to update the `destroy` action as below:

```
def destroy 
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to products_url  ## products_url notice plural products
end
```

`products_url` would redirect you to `index` page of `products`. 
As `product_path` is for `show`, i.e., to show a particular product. You can't show a deleted product that too without providing an `id` to `product_path`. So, logically you should be redirecting to `index` action with `products_url` (NOTE using `**_url` for redirection is advisable but you could also use `products_path`)

Answer (score 4):

Yes , destroy is controller's  delete method , to redirect to the product listing page you should use `redirect_to action: 'index'`. You can check all actions and method through command `rake routes`

Answer (score 4):

You should `redirect_to products_path`(this translates to `index`)
 since currently it says `redirect_to product path`(translating to `show`) which will throw error
`method: :delete` is for posting to `destroy` action and `can?` is a `cancan gem` method by *Ryan Bates*. The `if` checks if user has the permissions to delete the product or not.
The permissions can be set in `app/models/ability.rb`
Lastly change your routes to:

```
resources: :products
```